# Запись данных PHP в файл txt

Tags: php

Есть чекбоксы (их порядка 50 штук), которые передают данные в php файл, и эти данные нужно сохранить, я что то наковырял, и получается что после отправки формы с боксами, выходит файл php и в строку названия декоров, и сразу же сохранятся в файл.

Проблема в том что

1. сохраняется только последний декор (последнее значение), а не все
2. как убрать страницу php файла а вместо нее сделать просто страницу (сделаю сам) где благодарю за участие в опросе

как это выглядит можете посмотреть тут https://getalit.000webhostapp.com/index.html

```
<form action="decor.php" method="post">
<input type="checkbox" name="answer[]" value="L 115 [T]" id="abc"><p>L 115 [T]</p>
<input type="checkbox" name="answer[]" value="L 245 [T]" id="abc"><p>L 245 [T]</p>
<input type="checkbox" name="answer[]" value="L 441 [T]" id="abc"><p>L 441 [T]</p>
<input type="image" src="pic/button.png" alt="Отправить опрос" width="200">

    <?php
$name = $_POST['answer'];
foreach ($name as $answer){ 
    echo $answer."\n \n";
}
$user = fopen("result.txt","a+");
fwrite($user,"\n $answer \n"  . PHP_EOL);
fclose($user);
?>
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

$answer содержит последнее значение, которое вы зачем то используете вне цикла. Вы выводите результат почему то в цикле (вероятно для проверки), а сохраняете вне его. Делайте это тоже в цикле.

Правда не знаю как вы после этого будете в куче этих L 245 [T] разбираться. Данные лучше хранить в удобночитаемом для скрипта или человека виде, чтобы можно было потом обработать. И лучше в БД, а не в файлах.

Редирект делается с помощью установки заголовков функцией header().

```
<?php

$name = $_POST['answer'];

$user = fopen("result.txt", "a+");

foreach ($name as $answer) {
    //echo $answer . "\n \n";
    fwrite($user, "\n $answer \n" . PHP_EOL);
}

fclose($user);

header('Location: thanks.html');
```

Comment: Выдает такое Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at N:\home\dec.loc\www\decor.php:1) in N:\home\dec.loc\www\decor.php on line 14 , но как и хотелось сохраняет результат. Хорошо, а в какой БД лучше хранить данные, Access???

Comment: Значит перед <?php какой то вывод есть. Может пробел или что-то еще. Или файл с кодировкой utf-8 BOM. Можно старый удалить и новый создать файл. По поводу БД, в данном случае какую лучше знаешь имеешь в наличии, ту и использовать. Если совсем никакую не знаешь, то проще sqlite.

Comment: Спасибо, выручил сильно, а с БД уже потом разберусь!